# multiple-value in single-value context (go)

Tags: go

The code below returns the error `multiple-value  in single-value context`. I fail to understand why because it can't be more clear that the function has one argument ( I pass an empty string ""), and returns a string and an error (I assign it to `r` and `err`).

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Some struct{}

func main() {

    cl := Some{}
    r, err := &cl.Start("")
    fmt.Println(r)
}

func (cs *Some) Start(sg string) (string, error) {
    return sg, nil
}
```

Comment: Remove the `&` before `cl.Start`.

Comment: But I would like to use a pointer as the struct is bigger than in the example. Do I need a new identifier with the pointer? e.g clpointer := &cl

Comment: If you explicitly want to use a pointer to the struct I'd just have done `cl := &Some{}`.

Comment: @DaveC Well there are several operations on Some{} before to actually call Start thus the reason why it's not a pointer from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an operator precedence thing. `&cl.Start()` is the same as `&(cl.Start())`, which isn't what you want.

Use parentheses to clarify that what you want is `(&cl).Start()`.

Or you could just use a pointer variable.

```
func main() {
    cl := &Some{}
    r, err := cl.Start("")
    fmt.Println(r)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in the comment, remove the & from &cl.Start("") and it will work - though you'l then get an error about err being declared and not used.

Or you can write it as `(&cl).Start("")` and that too will work.

The explanation is [here](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#methods):

> The rule about pointers vs. values for receivers is that value methods can be invoked on pointers and values, but pointer methods can only be invoked on pointers.
>
> This rule arises because pointer methods can modify the receiver;
>   invoking them on a value would cause the method to receive a copy of
>   the value, so any modifications would be discarded. The language
>   therefore disallows this mistake. **There is a handy exception, though.
>   When the value is addressable, the language takes care of the common
>   case of invoking a pointer method on a value by inserting the address
>   operator automatically.**

and also [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls):

> A method call x.m() is valid if the method set of (the type of) x contains m and the argument list can be assigned to the parameter list of m. If x is addressable and &x's method set contains m, x.m() is shorthand for (&x).m()

Comment: The first explanation is pointless because I clearly tried to use a pointer value on a pointer method not a value on pointer method. ``(&x).m()`` works though &.m() felt more natural to me. Any idea why &x.m() is not working? I mean what does the compiler see on ``&x.m()``.

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything in the spec that explainsthis behaviour, however the error indicates that `cl.Start("") ` runs before the address operator is applied seeing that Start() returns 2 values. If you change it return a single value you will get `cannot take the address of cl.Start("")` as an error which further confirms this.

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat the first explanation isn't pointless, because that's how Go works. Your value is addressable, so it's automatically referenced for pointer receiver method calls. You almost never need to explicitly use the `&` for a method.